# Adding feedback feature to all pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model

I have got asp.net mvc 3 website, I want to add feedback feature to all pages.

I created the partial view for this purpose and render it in master layout.

```
    @model FeedbackHelper
    Name:<br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(o=>Model.Name)
```

for example in Questions page , MVC returns the exception because that page binded the **POST** entity, as far as I check in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550627/two-models-in-one-view-in-asp-mvc-3) I have got 2 solution

- create a parent model and add **POST** and **FeedbackHelper** as properties
- use **Tuple**

at the moment, changing all models is too risky for me.

Is there any good solution ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [child actions](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx). The idea is to define a specific controller action that will serve the partial view and then include it using the `@Html.Action` helper in your Layout.

So:

```
public ActionResult Feedback()
{
    FeedbackHelper model = ...
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

then you will of course have a partial in the Shared folder:

```
@model FeedbackHelper
Name:<br />
@Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.Name)
```

and include it in your Layout:

```
@Html.Action("Feedback", "ControllerContainingTheFeedbackAction")
```