# Multiple models in html

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, model

I'm trying to use multiple models in a single cshtml file.  The code I have is:

```
@model CostumeContest.Models.VoteModel  
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Vote";
}


<h2 style="color: #B45F04">Vote Receipt</h2>
<b>Your Name:</b> @Model.VoterName
<br />
<b>Your Vote for Best Costume: </b>@Model.BestName
<br />
<b>Your Vote for Most Creative Costume:</b> @Model.CreativeName
<br />

<h2 style="color: #B45F04">Vote Summary</h2>

//@model CostumeContest.Models.VoteResult    this is giving me problems when not commented out
<h3 style="color: #B45F04">Best Costume</h3>


<h3 style="color: #B45F04">Most Creative Costume</h3>
```

What is wrong with what I'm doing above, and more importantly, how can I solve my issue?  Thank you.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  What would your action look like?

Comment: Duplicate of [Two models in one view in ASP MVC 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550627/two-models-in-one-view-in-asp-mvc-3/7558510)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best bet is to make a view model that has everything you need in it.  Since your code is sparse, I'm going to take a shot in the dark:

```
namespace CostumeContest.Models
{
    public class MyViewModel
    {
        public VoteModel VoteModel { get; set; }
        public VoteResult VoteResult { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then change your first `@model` line to:

`@model CostumeContest.Models.MyViewModel`

Obviously, you'd change the name of the class to something that makes sense for you. You would then create a `MyViewModel` instance, set the `VoteModel` and `VoteResult` properties with it, and send the instance of the `MyViewModel` to the view, not a `VoteModel`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Tuple` to hold both objects.

```
@model Tuple<VoteModel, VoteResult>
```

Gromer's answer is a better design, but this is an easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a single outer model class with properties holding the other two classes.