# How to retrieve multiple Models From Single view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Is there a way to obtain a model object from the view into the controller without using strongly typed HTML helpers. The View uses the `Account` entity But need to post the form and retrieve the account entity of the variable running in a `foreach` loop used to generate the table/grid of values. The information from the dropdown is used for a different entity hence why its not strongly typed.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home
    ModelContext model = new ModelContext();


    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {


        return View(model.accounts.ToList());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Account account,List<string> status,string name)
    {
      // return student object
        return View();
    }
}
```

The rest of the code in the View runs on a `foreach` loop to generate an html `table` enclosed in a `@HTML.BeginForm`

```
<td>

        @Html.DropDownList("status",
        new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(ProjectName.Models.Code))),
        "...",
        new { @class = "form-control" })

</td>

<td>
    @Html.TextArea("comment");
</td>
```

Comment: Your `DropDownList()` method posts back only a single value so the parameter needs to be `string status` (not `List<string> status`). But having said that, you should be using view model containing all the properties you want in the view so you can strongly bind to it, get validation etc.

Comment: It returns an array of input because its running inside a foreach loop

Comment: Then you generating invalid html for a start! And you definitely need a view model to handle this properly

Comment: But how will the view model work with the Context Class? @StephenMuecke

Comment: What `Context` class? - are you referring to you db context? - is so, then there is no relationship to it - you map your data models to view models as vice-versa

Comment: I am retrieving data from the database using the dbcontext class initialised  in the controller noted above. in the view HTML helpers will only accept a single type.  if I create a 3rd class encapsulating both types i will no longer be able to access the db context mappings because its done on individual classes that map to database table names

Comment: [What is ViewModel in MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Answer (score 1):

You should be created a parent view model that includes both of these view models that you'll be needed in your view. For example:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ProjectName.Models.Code Code {get; set;} 
    public ProjectName.Models.Account Account {get; set;}
}
```

Also, please have a look [MVC - Multiple models in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360557/mvc-multiple-models-in-a-view?rq=1). I think it's good for you.

Hope this help!