# 2 models(tables) inside 1 view in Asp.net MVC4

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have Konu and Etiketler tables in database.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        SonerSevincComEntities context = new SonerSevincComEntities();

        var Konular = context.Konu.ToList();
        return View(Konular);
    }

}
```

In Konu Controller's View ,

I want to call Etiketler table and its Id.

I already use Konu Model But i want to use Etiketler Model in 1 View.

How can i call 2 tables(models)in 1 view page ?

Comment: **Duplicate** of the almost identically titled [Two models in one view in ASP MVC 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550627/two-models-in-one-view-in-asp-mvc-3). Please use the search.

Comment: create a ViewModel which references 2 tables..models

Comment: i am using entity CodeCaster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a ViewModel:

```
public class KonuEtiketlerViewModel
{
   public virtual List<Konu> Konus {get; set;}
   public virtual List<Etiketler> Etiketlers {get; set;}
}
```

and in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   SonerSevincComEntities context = new SonerSevincComEntities();
   var viewModel =  new KonuEtiketlerViewModel
   {
       Konus = context.Konu.ToList(),
       Etiketlers = context.Etiketler.ToList()
   }
   return View(viewModel);
}
```

View:

```
@model projectname.ViewModels.KonuEtiketlerViewModel // you must create a new class, preferably inside a ViewModels folder, called KonuEtiketlerViewModel
//you can access all your properties here....
```

Comment: SOfanatic , is it also for entity ?

Comment: @SonerSevinc what do you mean?

Comment: i am using entity framework for model. is there any difference for entity ?

Comment: Konus = context.Konu.ToList();
       Etiketlers = context.Etiketler.ToList();
Konus and Etiketlers dont work why ?

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work? are you getting an error, or it's not giving you the data you expect?

Comment: 1-konus and etiketlers Their under line red color. Maybe i must write something var konus or var etiketlers ? Because it is not working.

2-İn my view @model IEnumerable<SonerSevinc.Models.Konu>
Should i change this ?

Comment: @SonerSevinc see my edit, there should be a comma after `context.Konu.ToList(),` and nothing after `context.Etiketler.ToList()` . check answer for the view too.

Comment: there is a mistake in the code, in the view should be: @model projectname.ViewModels.KonuEtiketlerViewModel