# ASP MVC - How use two models in one single view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a web page that have two task
1) add new products
2) display existing products in a table (refer below image)

[image]

also i have two classes for each above task
for display existing details and save new product

```
public class VMProduct
{
    public List<Product>ProductList { get; set; } 
}

public class Product
{
    public String ProductID { get; set; }
    public String ProductName { get; set; }
    public String Uom1 { get; set; }
    public String  Uom2 { get; set; }
    public String ProductCategoryID { get; set; }
}
```

my problem is i can display data by using VMProduct.ProductList  model but how i can save new product items using "product" model ?

how can i use both Models in One view?
if i use "product" model's properties in VMProduct model it is duplication codes right?

can anyone have a Solution for this?
thanks in advance

Comment: Simple. Just create another class that has property of Product and VMProduct. Afterwards, you can supply that class to the view.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Two models in one view in ASP MVC 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550627/two-models-in-one-view-in-asp-mvc-3)

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764011/multiple-models-in-a-view, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763631/multiple-models-in-a-single-view-c-mvc3, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002213/asp-mvc-3-two-models-in-one-view

Comment: As far as your point about code duplication, you have to balance Single Responsibility (SRP) with DRY.  An update unit of work request model (for example: `AddProductRequest`) and a response model (for example: `ProductResults`, which is a `List<ProductResult>`) would both be good candidates to add to a single view model passed to the page.  The controller action would take the `AddProductRequest` as an argument, send it to the db, then re-select it as a `ProductgResult` and return it to the view via the ViewModel.  Properties will be duplicated, but their function is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `VMProduct` is already a custom view model (I'm mostly guessing by its name), so just add a property to it of the type you need:

```
public class VMProduct
{
    public List<Product> ProductList { get; set; }
    public Product NewProduct { get; set; }
}
```

Though, unless I'm misunderstanding something about your UX, this might not even be necessary.  The model used to *render* a view doesn't necessarily need to be the same model *received from any given form* on that view.  So you might continue to render the view using the `VMProduct` object you have now, and the form for adding a product can still post an instance of `Product` to the controller action which invokes the add operation.  Something like:

```
public ActionResult Add()
{
    // create your view model
    return View(someVMProduct);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(Product newProduct)
{
    // add the product to the backing data store
    return RedirectToAction("Add");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here explained how to implement 2 model in 1 view in MVC 4. Sometimes its required to implement a page where 2 forms exist in a single view (page)  like Login & Registration in a same view.

You can get complete tutorial here : http://dotnetawesome.blogspot.com/2013/09/2-model-in-1-view-in-mvc-4.html

Here is the sample code :

A ViewModel Created :

```
public class UsersLoginRegister
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Login Login { get; set; }
}
```

User Entity

```
public partial class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

Login Entity

```
 public class Login
{
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType( System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

In the view (Html) code :

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><b>Login</b></td>
    <td><b>Register</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Username : </td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Login.Username)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password : </td>
                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(a => a.Login.Password)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td> <input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        }
    </td>
    <td>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Fullname : </td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.User.FullName)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Username : </td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.User.Username)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password : </td>
                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(a => a.User.Password)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        }
    </td>
</tr>
```