# how to display two modles in a view and also attach a radio button group to each

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Ok I have a database called survey  just for testing purposes I have two tables Likert’s and questions  within  the likert table the following row are present Likert_ID ,Likert_ Description  in the questions table  I  have the following rows question_ID and question_Description  I’m using MVC and entity frame work 4 and also sql server 2014  the problem I’m having  is displaying both models in a view  and attaching a radio button group to each question based on the Likert_Description

Comment: possible duplicate of [Two models in one view in ASP MVC 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550627/two-models-in-one-view-in-asp-mvc-3)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please post the code you have tried and any errors you are getting. It will help the community provide answers to your problem.