# How to use more than two models in MVC razor view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, model, controller

I have used entity data model wizard to create an entity framework for my tables in the SQL server however I need to use more than two models in my razor view within MVC, currently I have an existing linq query in :

Controller View

```
var test = from a in db.tbl_users
       where a == 2
       select a;

return view (test.ToList());
```

Razor View:

```
@model IEnumerable <Telephone_Search.Models.tbl_users>

@foreach (var item in model)

@HTML.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.users)
```

However I plan to access other tables which exist in the Entity Framework which I want loop through, something like this

```
@model IEnumerable <Telephone_Search.Models.'EntityFramework'>

@foreach (var item in 'entityframework')

@HTML.DisplayFor(modelItem => EntityFramework.'table'.'item')
```

I have tried to create a view modal however my classes are separated within the model folder and I'm not sure how to wrap these classes into one view model?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two models in one view in ASP MVC 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550627/two-models-in-one-view-in-asp-mvc-3)

Comment: My models are in partial classes produced by the Entity Data Model Wizard , I need to find a method of placing a parent view model with these partial classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create a new class, usually called a ViewModel and pass the data in that class:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  public IEnumerable<Telephone_Search.Models.tbl_users> users;
  public IEnumerable<OtherType> otherThings;
  public string SomeOtherProp {get;set;}
}
```

In the view:

```
@model MyViewModel

foreach (var usr in Model.users) {...}
foreach (var ot in Model.OtherThings) {...}
<span>@Model.SomeOtherProp</span>
```

In the controller:

```
var test = from a in db.tbl_users
       where a == 2
       select a;

var otherTypes = from x in db.tbl_otherTypes where x.Prop > 10 select x;

return this.View(new MyViewModel
{
  users = test,
  otherThings = otherTypes,
  SomeOtherProp = "stackoverflow answer"
});
```

Comment: I gladly did so. However, do not use comments for thanking people. It is enough that you mark it as correct and upvote it. Taken from SO help: "Use comments to ask for more information or clarify a question or answer." ;)

Comment: Nevermind , I pointed at users instead of tbl_users in the razor. Working finally :) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

as directly we can not bind multiple model but there are other options to work with multiple models.

1. using Viewbag you can pass data of other modal

   ```
    ViewBag.Users = db.Students.ToList();
   ```

   in View Side

   ```
    @{
        var students = (List<Students>)ViewBag.Students;
     }
   ```
2. You can create Modal with properties contains object of other modal

   ```
    public class StudentViewModel
    {
         public string StudentName{get;set;}
         public IEnumerable<MarksheetViewModels> Results;          
    }
   ```