# Passing multiple models to a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-4.1

I'm having problems in passing multiple models to a single view, after reading other posts it I've gathered that I need to create a separate class and instantiate that class and return that instantiated class to the view. However, how would I do this ?

I wanted to use Entity Framework, and Linq to do the queries. If you can provide sample code for me to learn...

Comment: [Refer This][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764011/multiple-models-in-a-view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could either do it the quick and dirty way, using dynamic:

```
dynamic viewdata = new ExpandoObject();
viewdata.object1 = Model1;
viewdata.object2 = Model2;

return View(viewdata);
```

Or you could do it properly and create a viewmodel.

```
class ViewModel1 {
  public MyModel Model1 { get; set; }
  public MyOtherModel Model2 { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
ViewModel1 viewdata = new ViewModel1();
viewdata.Model1 = Model1;
viewdata.Model2 = Model2;

return View(viewdata);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    SomeClass1 object1 = new SomeClass1();
    SomeClass2 object2 = new SomeClass2();
    ViewData["someName1"]=object1;
    ViewData["someName2"]=object2;
    return View(ViewData);
}
```

In the View page you can access them as:

```
<% SomeClass1  object1 = ViewData["someName1"] as SomeClass1; %>
<% SomeClass1  object2 = ViewData["someName2"] as SomeClass2; %>
```

Comment: I would go for the other answer and use a sub ViewModel. All these magic strings and casting could/will be a pain to debug and only gives runtime errors.

Comment: @Syska "dynamic" keyword is introduced in c# 4.0!
what about previous frameworks then?

Comment: Then I would still go for the ViewModel that contains the 2 other view models. I dont really see the gain of this, unless you are just trying out some things in a little local project. I also started doing this, but in the end ... a really nightmere. I would avoid using dynamic if it can be done, unless we can some intellisence like R# is trying to provide, so we can catch errors in the build process.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view model.  A view model is a model that is typically made up of other models and is not bound to your data model. The MvcMusic demo has a good example of the use of view models.

While `ViewData` will work its not type safe and basically depends on magic strings, so I would avoid it.