# Passing form data to a model when using multiple models in the same view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core

How would you pass form data to a model (to be used inside my controller) when I have multiple models in a single view?

[I used this tutorial for multiple models in a view.](https://riptutorial.com/asp-net-mvc/example/31102/using-multiple-model-in-a-view-with-dynamic-expandoobject)

Index view and form (simplifed):

```
@using FlightBooker
@model dynamic

<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Search" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fromAirport">Flying from:</label>
                <select class="form-control">
                    @foreach (Airport airport in Model.Airports)
                    {
                        <option >@airport.AirportCode</option>
                    }

                </select>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="toAirport">Flying to:</label>
                    <select class="form-control">
                        @foreach (Airport airport in Model.Airports)
                        {
                            <option>@airport.AirportCode</option>
                        }

                    </select>
                </div>
                    <label for="fromAirport">Departure Date:</label>
                    <br />
                    <input type="date" / id="date" name="date">
                    <br />
                    <label for="fromAirport">No. passengers:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="passengers" name="passengers">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                    </select>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Search Flights</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

I was looking at this tutorial, this section: [Strongly type model binding to view](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/getting-data-from-view-to-controller-in-mvc/). I don't know how to apply this when I am using `@model dynamic`.

Or would I be better creating a View Model as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994419/passing-multiple-models-to-a-view)?

Comment: make a ViewModel Called "SearchViewModel", 
add properties with the name same as the html names of input fields  
for exmaple 
public class SearchViewModel
{
public datetime date {get;set;}
}

when u put it as a parameter of the action called search it will automatically bind to the values.


Note : add the values of the select inside of the html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I'm gonna tell you what to do here.....

**the model is used to render data from controller to the view.**

if you want to pass data from view to controller there are some simpler ways...

**step1:**

set all of the html **input/select** elements the value of `Name`

Example :

```
  <select class="form-control" name"AirportsDdl">
            @foreach (Airport airport in Model.Airports)
            {
                <option value="@airport.AirportCode">@airport.AirportCode</option>
            }

        </select>

<input type="date" / id="date" name="date">
```

**Notice that the Select must have a value**

**Step2**

then you make a ViewModel like this

```
public class SearchViewModel
{
public datetime date {get;set;}
public int AirportsDdl {get;set;}
}
```

**step3:**

then in your action :

```
ActionResult Search(SearchViewModel sreachData)
{
//put your filter here
return view();
}
```

then you all set

Comment: I had done step 2 and 3 already, it was step 1 I was missing. Seeing it laid out like this has helped massively, thanks :)