# Display data from multiple models in one view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

In the MVC 3 i want to display data from two models viz. Student and Enrollment into a single view.
**Student model**

```
public class Student
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int student_id { get; set; }

        public string student_name { get; set; }
        public string father { get; set; }
    }
```

**Enrollment model**

```
public class Enrollment
    {
        [Key]
        public int enrollment_id { get; set; }
        public string rollno { get; set; }
        public int student_id { get; set; }
        public string registration_no { get; set; }
        public date registration_date { get; set; }
}
```

**My ViewModel looks like this**

```
 public class StudentEnrollmentViewModel
    {
        public Student_Info Student_Info { get; set; }
        public Enrollment_Info Enrollment_Info { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

How do I retrieve the data from the two model and assign it to a viewmodel so that I can display it in a view? I am using Repository Design Pattern.

Comment: Try this post for answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764011/multiple-models-in-a-view

Answer (score 0):

You can use DynamicPage, Look into following example

We need to use a Dynamic view page. ([More Information](http://lostechies.com/seanbiefeld/2010/06/23/dynamic-view-page-mvc-without-a-view-model/))
Follow following steps:

1. Create DynamicViewPage type

   ```
   public class DynamicViewPage : ViewPage
   {
      public new dynamic Model { get; private set; }    
      protected override void SetViewData(ViewDataDictionary viewData)
       {
           base.SetViewData(viewData);
           Model =  ViewData.Model;
       }`
   }
   ```
2. Your Controller will look like

   ```
   public ActionResult Account(string returnUrl)
   {
       LoginModel loginmodel = null;//Initialize Model;
       RegistrationModel registrationModel = null ;//Initialize Model;
      // Any Extra logic
       return View("Account", new
       {
           Login = loginmodel,
           Register = registrationModel
       });
   }
   ```
3. your View should Inherit from

   ```
   Inherits="DynamicViewPage"
   ```

Now `@Model.Login` will give you `Loginmodel`

`@Model.Register` will give you `RegisterModel`

It should work as you expected.........

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply... Will look into it :)

Comment: I don't know about dynamic page. Because I would also like to use the viewmodel for CRUD operations.

Comment: [http://lostechies.com/seanbiefeld/2010/06/23/dynamic-view-page-mvc-without-a-view-model/] will give you detail about Dynamic page. You Still can use CRUD operation as i assume data from different model will have different forms and different partial views.

Comment: LINK: http://lostechies.com/seanbiefeld/2010/06/23/dynamic-view-page-mvc-without-a-view-model/

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, a controller would be responsible for contacting the model, storing the result set returned in a variable/array/struc that the view would consume.  The model and view components/classes would be registered in the controller.

An example:

```
<event-handler event="display.institutions" access="public">            
    <notify listener="userInstitutionRights" method="getInstitutionsWithDataRightsNOXML" resultKey="request.institutions" />

    <view-page name="userNav" contentKey="request.userNav"/>
    <view-page name="userInstitutions" contentKey="request.pageContent"/>

    <announce event="assemblePage" />
</event-handler>
```

Event display.institutions is calling a model component userInstitutionRights and storing the result in a resultKey request.institutions and is including two view pages userNav, userInstitutions where the resultKey is available to each.