# Display form for creating new message along with message list in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I've created model `Message` and showing list of these messages on `Index` view of my site. The controller passes `IEnumerable<Models.Message>` object to the view.

To display all these messages I'm iterating through them using `@foreach`. But I also want to create form on the same `Index` view to create new message. Seems to be easy task, but call to `@Html.TextAreaFor(Model.Body)` gives me following error:

`CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Models.Message>' does not contain a definition for 'Body' and no extension method 'Body' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Models.Message>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Is it possible to create form based on `Models.Message`, despite fact that view as created based upon `IEnumerable<Models.Message>`?

My model is:

```cs
public class Message
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public Citizen From { get; set; }
    public Citizen To { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public bool IsPrivate { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT:** Frankly I don't want to create an additional model holding one message for form and list of messages for display, mostly since in form action controller I need to deal with this "extended" model. I think cleaner would be to have original `Message` there.

But how?

Comment: Can you post up your model and also you view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. You will have to create a (View)Model for this particular view, with all the necessary properties like this:

```
public class IndexViewModel(){

    public IEnumerable<Models.Message> Messages {get;set; }

    public string Body {get;set;}

    //any other properties for your form

}
```

In your Controller, create this ViewModel and populate it:

```
public ActionResult Index(){

    var vm = new IndexViewModel();
    vm.Messages = GetMessages();

    return View(vm);
}
```

In your view, set this ViewModel as the model, and you can iterate through the messages by using Model.Messages, and create a textarea using TextAreaFor(x => Model.Body)

Comment: I got the approach, the simple answer: I need additional model to handle this situation.

Comment: However... This means that in action controller I cannot accept original `Message` model. I need to use new one. What looks a bit ugly to me, since that new model contains definition of messages list. Redundant in this case... Is it possible to avoid this?

Comment: That's the downside of this. I haven't found a real solution to this. You could put the Message-List in a ViewBag, so you don't have to put them in the ViewModel.

Comment: Currently I'm investigating following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764011/multiple-models-in-a-view