# ASP.NET MVC 4 - multiple models in one view

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, mvvm

I'm just began new project, using ASP.NET MVC 4, and I have question.

How I may use multiple models (or ViewModel-s) in one view? I'm searched over Internet, and standard solution is *"create complex viewmodel with 2 or more properties"*, e.g.:

```
public class ComplexViewModel   
{
    public LoginModel LoginModel { get; set; }
    public CartModel CartModel { get; set; }
}
```

But, for example, in each page I'll have **at least** 2 model - LoginModel and another model (depends on page). So, I need to define LoginModel in each ViewModel?

P.S.: I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4, Entity Framework 5.

Comment: You can use PartialView within your main view, which can contain its own separate model. Perhaps try to research this, there are lots of good tutorials out there

Comment: If you have the LoginModel in many other models you can create a seperate class for LoginModel and inherit this class in all your other models.

Comment: You can have base class with those model properties.

Comment: @Longball27, big thnx, I'm used [**this solution**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764011/multiple-models-in-a-view)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create BaseViewModel and define LoginModel property and inherit all View Models from BaseViewModel so you don't need to define LoginModel in every View Models you will create.

```
public class BaseViewModel
{
    public LoginModel LoginModel { get; set; }
}

public class ComplexViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public CartModel CartModel { get; set; }
}
```