# Multiple models in view ASP.NETMVC (PartialView Approach)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Last days I learning ASP.NET MVC. I have a problem when I would use two or more models in "master" view.

Model one:

```
 public class PersonController : Controller
{
    private Context ctx = new Context();
    public IEnumerable<Employer> employersCol { get;set; }
    // GET: Person]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        employersCol = ctx.employers.ToList();
        return View(ctx.persons.ToList());
    }
}
```

Model two:

```
 public class EmployerController : Controller
    {
        private Context ctx = new Context();
        // GET: Employer
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(ctx.employers.ToList());
        }
    }
```

so, now in "master" view I would to display data:

```
@foreach (var p in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => p.firstName);
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => p.lastName);
}
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Employer/_emp.cshtml")
```

but the Visual Studio say:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The model item passed into the dictionary is
>   of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WebApplication7.Models.Person]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WebApplication7.Models.Employer]'.

The question is: how Can I pass the type to the partial view. Maybe you prefer another approach. Hm.. maybe I have to use Ajax.. but how?

Comment: Please post your complete View code

Comment: Which action you are calling? from PersonController  index or EmployerController  index?

Comment: Hope this both link will help you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764011/multiple-models-in-a-view

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/multiple-models-in-single-view-in-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

By default, Razor will pass the page model down to the partial. Therefore, assuming the `_emp.cshtml` view has a model of `IEnumerable<Employee>` rather than `IEnumerable<Person>` then you can use the overload for `@Html.Partial` to override the model

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Employer/_emp.cshtml", Model.Cast<Employee>())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This (dont have a machine running vs right now) but should work

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Employer/_emp.cshtml", model.Employer) ; // the property name by which u expose your model, if your model is not an Arraylist, then you need to loop through it.
```