# How to use @model IEnumerable<> and @model <> in the same page MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In the razor view how can i use @model IEnumerable<> and @model <> ? for single page application

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764011/multiple-models-in-a-view/56705869#56705869

Answer (score 0):

how much i am getting according to your situation you want to pass multiple models on a single view. so for that condition you can use " Tuple "

Example :

```
Tuple<IEnumerable(ProjectName.FolderName.Classname),ProjectName.FolderName.Class1name>
```

you can use tuple to pass multiple models on single View.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your view with only a single model. If you want to have multiple models in your view then you should create a model and wrap them into this `ViewModel`

So for example if you have you models like such -

```
public class OrdersModel
{
    //Properties...
}

public class CustomerPersonalInfoModel
{
    //Properties...
}
```

...and you need to bind them with your view, create a view model for them -

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public System.Collections.Generic.List<OrdersModel> Orders { get; set; }
    public CustomerPersonalInfoModel PersonalInfo { get; set; }
}
```

then you can bind your view with `CustomerViewModel`.