# how to combine with two model in the view (ASP.net MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Two model have combined to exist in view

1.~/Products.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ShoppingStore.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set;}
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set;  }
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }
}
```

2.~/PorductListViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

using ShoppingStore.Domain.Entities;

namespace ShoppingStore.WebUI.Models
{
    public class ProductsListViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public PagingInfo PageInfo { get; set; }
        public string CurrentCategory { get; set; }
    }
}
```

3.control  ~/ProductController.cs 
public ViewResult List(string category , int page=1)

```
{
            ProductsListViewModel model = new ProductsListViewModel
            {
               Products = repository.Products.Where(p => category ==null || p.Category ==category).OrderBy(p => p.ProductID).Skip((page - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize),
                PageInfo = new PagingInfo {CurentPage = page,ItemPerPage = PageSize,TotalItems = category == null ? repository.Products.Count() : repository.Products.Where(e => e.Category == category).Count()},
                CurrentCategory = category
            }; 
            return View(model);
}
```

i use this way 
[Multiple models in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764011/multiple-models-in-a-view)

and add two model in one model

1.~/MainPageModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using ShoppingStore.Domain.Entities;

namespace ShoppingStore.WebUI.Models
{
    public class MainPageModel
    {
        public ProductsListViewModel ProductsListViewModel { get; set; }
        public Product Product { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and chnage code like below

~/List.cshtml

```
@model ShoppingStore.WebUI.Models.MainPageModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Prodcuts";

}
@foreach (var p in Model.PorductListViewModel.Products)
{

 @Html.Partial("ProductSummary",p)
}


<div>
    @Html.PageLinks(Model.PorductListViewModel.PageInfo, x => Url.Action("List", new { page = x , category = Model.PorductListViewModel.CurrentCategory }))
</div>

<div>
         @using (Html.BeginForm())
         {

            <div >
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Product.ProductID)
                @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery)
                <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" />
            </div>

            <div>
                <div id='DIV2'><input type="button" onclick="incrementValue1()" value="ADD" /></div>
                <div id="DIV2"> <input type="text" id="number1" value="0" /></div>
                <div id="DIV2"><input type="button" onclick="decrementValue1()" value="minus" /></div>
            </div>
            <button id="checkvalue" onclick="checkValue()" type="submit">Check</button>
         </div>

    }
```

When Running , IIS have below error message .

**The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'ShoppingStore.WebUI.Models.ProductsListViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'ShoppingStore.WebUI.Models.MainPageModel'.**

why have this error message

Comment: How do you call the view? From a controller? From other view? Show us all the relevant code. But the problem is easy, you must be doing something like `return View("List", new ProductsListViewModel())` instead of `return View("List", new MainPageModel())`

Comment: Share your controller return View() details

Comment: The error is self explanatory really the model required is ShoppingStore.WebUI.Models.MainPageModel and you are using ShoppingStore.WebUI.Models.ProductsListViewModel in your view, Change the model passed in by the controller and do some kinds of mapping

Comment: i add my control , thx for your replay

Answer (score 1):

Its seems you are returning wrong model to view "**@model ShoppingStore.WebUI.Models.MainPageModel**".

Your Code looks good but you need to check your controller return view details its should be like :

```
public ActionResult ViewAction()
{

MainPageModel objMainPageModel = new MainPageModel();
objMainPageModel.ProductsListViewModel = new ProductsListViewModel();
objMainPageModel.ProductsListViewModel= //Bind this model as well

//Bind Data in objMainPageModel and return to view
return View("List", objMainPageModel)

}
```

Comment: you mean i add my control like below code

Comment: Your controller action code should be like this.

Comment: it seem donot work ,it will tell me "ProductsListViewModel " does not exist in the type "MainPageModel"

Comment: Have you added MainPageModel objMainPageModel = new MainPageModel();
objMainPageModel.ProductsListViewModel = new ProductsListViewModel(); this in your controller action

Comment: yes , i add  it change like below code  'public ViewResult List(string category , int page=1)
        {
            MainPageModel objMainPageModel = new MainPageModel ();
            objMainPageModel.ProductsListViewModel = new ProductsListViewModel() ;              
             ProductsListViewModel model = new ProductsListViewModel

            {
                ///
            };     
            return View("List" , objMainPageModel);
        }'

Comment: Have you bind PorductListViewModel.Products inside the action as well

Comment: Share your controller action full code.

Comment: you mean "repository.Products"

Comment: No dude just public ActionResult ViewAction()

Comment: i work , thx a lot

Comment: Great Please mark this ans as a Accepted