# Creating a View with two models

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I current have two models that are independent from each other but want to combine them in one view based on the month they were created.

```
 class Distance{
     public int Id{get;set;}
     public float DistanceRan { get; set;}
     public DateTime DateTime {get;  set;}
 }
```

and

```
 class Weight{
     public int Id{get;set;}
     public float CurrentWeight{ get; set;}
     public DateTime DateTime {get;  set;}
 }
```

I want to be able to create a view with the dates of the month: 1-12, that when clicked on would then take you to a page that would have each record of Weight/Distance that corresponds to that month.

I would assume I create a model such as:

```
 class WeightDistance{
     public int Id{get;set;}
     public List<Distance> Distance{ get; set;}
     public List<Weight> Weight{get;  set;}
 }
```

The logic behind getting each month isn't an issue, the problem is combining them both into a view. How would I go about creating a way to display these together? Would I create myself a controller to pull the data?

I have created a project before that had an Announcement Model and Comment Model, where it had a ModelView that would display all the comments in the details section of the announcement but the link was:

> /Announcement/3/Details

Whereas this monthly view I want it to be:

> /Month/2/...

Does that require a controller? Sorry I'm quite new and am finding it hard to find specific resources.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple models in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764011/multiple-models-in-a-view)

Comment: @DavidG I understand it maybe a duplicate but the reason I ask is wouldn't I need some proper C# code to pull the rows from each Table where Date=Date

Comment: Well yes, some C# code will be needed.

Comment: @DavidG how useful

Comment: Well we're not here to write code for you I'm afraid.

Comment: @DavidG where in my question does it say to write code?

Comment: How else could we answer the question then?

Comment: @DavidG I literally asked, would I need a controller or not.

Comment: I think you would need a ViewModel

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc

Answer (score 0):

Upload data into each model, then

```
class WeightDistance{
         public int Id{get;set;}
         public List<Distance> Distance{ get; set;}
         public List<Weight> Weight{get;  set;}
     }
```

Create View with that model. Then Create two partial views for 'Distance' and 'Weight' list. And then call those two partials form Parent view:

```
@Html.Partial("NameOfPartial",Distance)
@Html.Partial("NameOfPartial",Weight)
```

If you want to use two lists with mixed HTML, just create partials for single objects and iterate throw the lists calling the partials

```
foreach(var item in Distance)
{
  @Html.Partial("NameOfPartialForSingleObject",item)
}
foreach(var item in Weight)
{
  @Html.Partial("NameOfPartialForSingleObject",item)
}
```

Would I create myself a controller to pull the data? Yes, of course. But only parent view would need controller logic