# Asp.net MVC, how to add Multiple model at one view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have tried to add multiple models in one view at asp.net MVC, but this show me error like this:

```
Line 1:  @using myapp.Models;
Line 2:  @model appViewModel
Line 3:  @model ForgotPasswordViewModel
Line 4:
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: try combining all models into one single view-model and import it to views.

Comment: You can't use two `@model` directive like that. See [Multiple models in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764011/multiple-models-in-a-view) post to learn joining data models into single viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly add multiple Model to one view 
Instead you can do something like this (Combining all models in to a single Model)

```html
Line 1:  @using myapp.Models;
Line 2:  @model MyMultpileViewModel
 


/**Your Model **/
class MyMultpileViewModel
{
 public AppViewModel appViewModel{get;set;} // First Model
 public ForgotPasswordViewModel forgotPasswordViewModel{get;set;}  // Second Model
}
```

Comment: Its Actually I have a index file and at this view file I have multiple module loading by jquery actions, but i want separate each model for each actions 
for example add people
delete people

for add people i want add a model in a separate file in models folder

how can i do that

Comment: Please share your code for better understanding of your issue

Answer (score 0):

Create a View Model(Class) containing both classes as members and return that as model from controller.

Comment: can you elaborate it more please?