# How to use multiple models in one MVC view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model, viewbag

I'm having problems using 2 different models for one MVC view. I have a page which can switch between 2 contents by a toggle button. One content shows a list of redirects(model ApiRedirects) which works fine and my other content has to show a list of companies(model Companies). Look screenshots:

Content 1(works):

[image]

Now I switch to my other content using the toggle button position in the top center which will enable to show the other view:

[image]

In the last view(model Companies) I want to be able to display a list of my Companies table of my database, however I'm not able to do this because I cant figure out how to import 2 models in one view.

**What I've tried so far**

In my controller im returning a list of my ApiRedirects and use this in my view by using(works for one model):

```
@model List<APIBrokerFrontend.Models.ApiRedirect>
```

However I cannot do this twice so I've tried obtaining a list of **Companies** in my controller and put this list in a ViewBag. This works and I get my list in my view but when I try to create a TextBox element by doing this:

```
var getlist = ViewBag.CompaniesList as IEnumerable<APIBrokerFrontend.Models.Company>;

<div class="modal-body">
       <form id="myForm">
       @<p>@Html.TextBoxFor(getlist.First().CompanyName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Company Name" })</p>
        </form>
</div>
```

I'm getting the following error:

[image]

Hope somebody got a solution for this!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple models in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764011/multiple-models-in-a-view)

Comment: [ViewModels](https://duncanhalley.co.uk/blog/multiple-models-in-one-view-viewmodels-in-asp-net-mvc/).

Answer (score 0):

The last view you can simply use @Url.Action("ActionName"). Create a PartialViewResult in the controller.