# How to inject a repository in a controller when repository is not known at controller construction time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an application, where I do not know the full list of repositories a controller might need upfront (at the time the controller is constructed). A controller gets a list of "components" to render from the database, and then which additional repositories are needed depends on what "components" the database returns. Is there a way to inject these repositories? I'm using ninject although it probably does not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time I wrote my question, my "components" were implemented as partial views, and I rendered them from a view executed (Html.Partial) from a controller action. Thanks to [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287015/create-controller-for-partial-view-in-asp-net-mvc) I changes this model, so that each of my "components" has it's own controller and instead of rendering partial view directly, actions marked with `ChildActionOnly` on these controllers are called from the view (Html.Action). This is done similar to what is described in the [article linked in the original answer](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx/), although in my case the view engine was razor.

This way the whole problem does not exist any more - each component controller knows about its repositories now.

Answer (score 1):

Make your repositories a dependency within your component. Most IOC software like Ninject will inject all the required dependancies for an object when you resolve it.

For example:

```
public class ComponentA : IComponent
{
    public IRepository RepositoryA {get;set;}
}

public class ComponentB : IComponent
{
    public IRepository RepositoryAnother {get;set;}
}
```

Whenever you load ComponentA or B its dependencies (in this case a IRepository) should get loaded as well.

So you don't need to know what Repository is required.