# How to use a controller for a partial view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following mockup.

[image]

I need that the user profile on the top left is dinamically loaded, so I splitted the navigation.cshtml into two files.

Navigation.cshtml

```
<nav class="navbar-default navbar-static-side" role="navigation">
    <div class="sidebar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
            <li class="nav-header">
                <!-- Top Navbar -->
                @Html.Partial("_Profile")

            </li>
            <li class="@Html.IsSelected(action: "Index")">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i> <span class="nav-label">Main page</span> </a>
            </li>
            <li class="@Html.IsSelected(action: "Minor")">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Minor", "Home")"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> <span class="nav-label">Minor page</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

and profile.cshtml

```
<div class="dropdown profile-element">
    <span>
        <img alt="image" class="img-circle" src="~/Images/profile_small.jpg" />
    </span>
    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
        <span class="clear">
            <span class="block m-t-xs">
                <strong class="font-bold">David Williams</strong>
            </span> <span class="text-muted text-xs block">Art Director <b class="caret"></b></span>
        </span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeInRight m-t-xs">
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Profile", "AppViews")">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Contacts", "AppViews")">Contacts</a></li>
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Inbox", "Mailbox")">Mailbox</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Login", "Pages")">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="logo-element">
    IN+
</div>
```

and I have one controller that will return the name of the user.

```
 public class UserProfileController : Controller
    {
        // GET: UserProfile
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetPropertiesForUser()
        {
            Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(SettingsHelper.AzureAdGraphApiEndPoint);
            var token = await AppToken.GetAppTokenAsync();

            ActiveDirectoryClient adClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(
             serviceRoot,
             async () => await AppToken.GetAppTokenAsync());
            string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;

            Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Application app = (Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Application)adClient.Applications.Where(
                a => a.AppId == SettingsHelper.ClientId).ExecuteSingleAsync().Result;
            if (app == null)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Unable to get a reference to application in Azure AD.");
            }

            string requestUrl = string.Format("https://graph.windows.net/{0}/users/{1}?api-version=1.5", SettingsHelper.Tenant,ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First().Name);

            HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
            hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue(
                "Bearer", token);

            HttpResponseMessage hrm = await hc.GetAsync(new Uri(requestUrl));

            if (hrm.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string jsonresult = await hrm.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return View("GetPropertiesForUser", new UserProfile
                {
                    DisplayName = jsonresult //I am still missing here to get the display name only
                });
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

    }
```

The thing I dont know how to do

How can I use a controller with a partial view?

UPDATE 1.

I updated the code as suggested by users below:

```
<nav class="navbar-default navbar-static-side" role="navigation">
    <div class="sidebar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
            <li class="nav-header">
                <!-- Top Navbar -->
          @{ Html.RenderAction("GetPropertiesForUser", "UserProfile"); }
            </li>
            <li class="@Html.IsSelected(action: "Index")">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i> <span class="nav-label">Main page</span> </a>
            </li>
            <li class="@Html.IsSelected(action: "Minor")">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Minor", "Home")"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> <span class="nav-label">Minor page</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>


 public class UserProfileController : Controller
    {
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetPropertiesForUser()
        {
            Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(SettingsHelper.AzureAdGraphApiEndPoint);
            var token = await AppToken.GetAppTokenAsync();

            ActiveDirectoryClient adClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(
             serviceRoot,
             async () => await AppToken.GetAppTokenAsync());
            string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;

            Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Application app = (Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Application)adClient.Applications.Where(
                a => a.AppId == SettingsHelper.ClientId).ExecuteSingleAsync().Result;
            if (app == null)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Unable to get a reference to application in Azure AD.");
            }

            string requestUrl = string.Format("https://graph.windows.net/{0}/users/{1}?api-version=1.5", SettingsHelper.Tenant,ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First().Name);

            HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
            hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue(
                "Bearer", token);

            HttpResponseMessage hrm = await hc.GetAsync(new Uri(requestUrl));

            if (hrm.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                UserProfile up = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserProfile>(await hrm.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                return PartialView(up);
                //return View("GetPropertiesForUser", new UserProfile
                //{
                //    DisplayName = up.displayName() //I am still missing here to get the display name only
                //});
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

    }

@model Inspinia_MVC5_Capatech.Models.UserProfile
<div class="dropdown profile-element">
    <span>
        <img a...
```

However I get this error:
http://screencast.com/t/8VKj4Hwg

The partial view name is called _Profile.cshtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using Html.Partial you can use Html.Action or Html.RenderAction, pointing to the controller action. Somethign like:

```
        <li class="nav-header">
            <!-- Top Navbar -->
            @Html.Action("GetPropertiesForUser")
```

Make sure to return `PartialView()` from the Controller instead of `View()`.

Regarding the error in **Update 1**, you need to use the naming convention (shared name between Action and View) or indicate the name of the view.
In your case I think you need to replace the return to something like:

```
return PartialView("_Profile");
```

Comment: I read some that render action would cause 2 rountrips to the server, is that correct?

Comment: @EstebanV please provide a link - there is no extra roundtrip to render child actions. Note - it is not clear whether you've read link wrong or it just plain wrong.

Comment: here its, on the comments. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287015/create-controller-for-partial-view-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 4):

Actually you need a **ChildAction** with **Partial View** since you want **GetPropertiesForUser** action to use **profile.cshtml** view.

```
public class UserProfileController : Controller
{
   [ChildActionOnly]
   public ActionResult GetPropertiesForUser()
   {
      // ...
     return PartialView(...);
   }
}
```

### Usage

```
@Html.Action("GetPropertiesForUser", "UserProfile")
```

OR

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("GetPropertiesForUser", "UserProfile"); }
```

Comment: Child actions can't be async... VNext support asynchronous view components, but syntax is different.