# ASP.NET MVC Bootstrab Tabs click with Controller\Action issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tabs

**Question**: In a Bootstrap Tabs panel, how can we display an MVC View page in the corresponding tab-content area?

**Details**: Following example (taken from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp)) works fine in my ASP.NET MVC Core project. But, using `anchor tag helper` I want to call an action method when user clicks on a tab; when I do that I get the following error. For example, I get this error when in tab `Menu 1` I use `asp-controller` and `asp-action` attributes as follows. I know the error is related to `href` attribute that is related to the corresponding tab contents. Is there a workaround so we can still call an action method when a tab is clicked?:

**Error**:

`Cannot override the 'href' attribute for <a>`.

**Error is on this line**: `<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1" asp-controller="myController asp-action="myAction">Menu 1</a></li>`

**Following works if anchor tag helper is not used**:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to call `@Html.RenderAction()` inside the required tab content. Leave the href as they are, there purpose is only to show the corresponding tab based on tab id.

See the following Question:
[Create controller for partial view in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287015/create-controller-for-partial-view-in-asp-net-mvc)