# How to implement a dashboard page using MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 web app. One of its pages should be something like a ‘dashboard’: to display several information blocks. Each of the block will have its one model-controller-view objects.
The question is: how to implement it? I have just started working with MVC; so any info would be helpful

Comment: Unfortunately your question has far too much scope for an answer you really need to check up [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](How to ask a good question) and I would recommend following the Microsoft Guides on starting with MVC primarily by Rick Anderson which are extremely helpful and will get you understanding the basics first. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio](basics of MVC) and then try googling how to create a dashboard in MVC there are so many guides. Good Luck.

Comment: Take a look at Partial Views. The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287015/create-controller-for-partial-view-in-asp-net-mvc) has some good info.