# How to include a razor page to another razor page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'd like to know how to include another razor page in running razor view just as PHP's "include" term. It can be considered as partial classes. Half of work is done at a.cshtml and the other half of works are done at b.cshtml. But in reality two of them are built as one razor page.

Any ideas will be appreciated...

Comment: Did you have a look at the standard MVC startup projects?

Comment: What is your purpose to ask this question?

Comment: @Mesut, what is the purpose of the separation between a.cshtml and b.cshtml?

Comment: Please refer to my answer to @Kundan Singh Chouhan.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Partial Views in MVC.

Try **[RenderAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.renderaction%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)** or **[RenderPartial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.renderpartialextensions.renderpartial%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)** methods to render another view or partial view in a current view.

**More Reference :**

[RenderAction RenderPartial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719027/renderaction-renderpartial)

[Html.Partial vs Html.RenderPartial & Html.Action vs Html.RenderAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248183/html-partial-vs-html-renderpartial-html-action-vs-html-renderaction)

Comment: @Mesut, so do you need some other thing?

Comment: Yes, Suppose that I've two works to do. Such as tables are in a.cshtml and div's are in b.cshtml. But When I call action it combines two of razor pages, and gives me only one output. No RenderPartial or RenderPage methods. Because my main purpose is getting intellisense of a.cshtml while in b.cshtml. Again suppose that I initialized a variable called "customers" in a.cshtml, then I'd like to see this at b.cshtml's intelli sense.

Comment: @Mesut, why didn't you put that in the question?