# How to render a partial view from a different model/controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I have the following partial view called _Categories residing in ~/Views/Category/_Categories:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyBlogSite.Models.BlogPostCategory>

<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</li>
}
</ul>
```

I have the following Index view at ~/Views/Blog/Index.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyBlogSite.Models.BlogPost>

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }

@Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Category/_Categories.cshtml", ---- );

<p>
   @Html.ActionLink("New Blog Post", "Create")
</p>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
    </th>       
    ...
```

In the space of the dashes (----) above is where I have been trying to figure out how to pass the model in. I cannot use Model.BlogPostCategory because it only accepts Model.BlogPost. I have also tried "model" with a lower-case "m" as per a couple of posts that I saw here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I create *viewmodel* for my *partialview*, then pass its data. For example:
my viewmodel

```
public class CompanyCreateViewModel
{
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public IList<CompanyContact> CompanyContacts { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<ContactType> ContactTypes { get; set; }
}
```

*partialview*

```
@model Invoice.Model.HelperClasses.CompanyCreateViewModel
---
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Company.FullName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Company.FullName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Company.ShortName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Company.ShortName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Company.TIN)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Company.TIN)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Company.Address.Country)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Company.Address.City)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Company.Address.Street)
    </div>    
    ---
```

and View with calling *partialview*

```
@model Invoice.Model.HelperClasses.CompanyViewModel
---
<div id="CompanyCreateModal" class="modal hide fade">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("CompanyParts/CompanyCreateModal", new Invoice.Model.HelperClasses.CompanyCreateViewModel() { ContactTypes = Model.ContactTypes });
    }
</div>
----
```