# How to feature a page in another page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

On my home(index) page I would like to have the login form sit directly in my home page if the user is not logged in but if the user has logged in already the index page will be displayed. If I use `_LoginPartial` this page is loaded as expected, But with other pages in folders such as Account I get an error

CSHTML:

```
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <p> Welcome to my website</p>
}
else
{
    @await Html.PartialAsync("Account/Login")
}
```

> `InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the
>   ViewDataDictionary is of type 'CS.Pages.Manifest.IndexModel', but this
>   ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type
>   'CS.Pages.Account.LoginModel'.

LoginModel Constructor:

```
public LoginModel(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, ILogger<LoginModel> logger)
{
    _signInManager = signInManager;
    _logger = logger;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you load a partial like:

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("Account/Login")
```

The model of the view you're calling it from is passed in implicitly, just as if you had done:

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("Account/Login", Model)
```

Hence, the error your received. The partial expects a model of type `LoginModel` but you're passing it a model of type `IndexModel`. The solution of course is to pass in a model of the right type, i.e. `LoginModel`. However, your `LoginModel`  has to be constructed with with parameters of types `SignInManager<ApplicationUser>` and `ILogger<LoginModel`. Hence why you received the second error when you attempted to pass just `new LoginModel()`.

All this really boils down to this being an improper use of a partial, in the first place. A partial that requires this complex of instantiation should really be a [*view component*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components) instead, which would give you a ton more flexibility with setup *and* allows you to do injection, which is what you're going to need here.

Essentially, you just create a class that inherits from `ViewComponent` and implements the method `InvokeAsync`:

```
public class LoginViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly ILogger<LoginModel> _logger;

    public LoginViewComponent(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, ILogger<LoginModel> logger)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        var model = await GetModelAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return View(model);
    }

    public Task<LoginModel> GetModelAsync()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new LoginModel(_signInManager, _logger));
    }
}
```

Notice that the view component's constructor takes the parameters you need to instantiate your `LoginModel` with. This allows these dependencies to be injected by the framework. The constructor, then, merely stores these in some private fields.

The `InvokeAsync` method calls `GetModelAsync` to get the `LoginModel` instance, and then returns a view that uses this model. Since, here, there's no actual async work that needs to be done, the `GetModelAsync` method just returns a `Task` created from the result of newing up a `LoginModel`. This has to be done to satisfy the `Task`-returning nature of `InvokeAsync`. If you actually needed to something asynchronous, you could simply await here instead.

With that in place, you just need to create the view `Views\Shared\Components\Login\Default.cshtml`. Which would have the contents of the partial view you're currently using. The `Login\Default.cshtml` portion is by convention. The directory is the name of the view component class, minus the `ViewComponent` suffix, and `Default.cshtml` is the default view it will look for there. This can be customized, if you like, but there's really no reason to.

Finally, where you want this appear, you simply call:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("Login");
```

With is approach, all the functionality (including the creation and passing in of the model) is all self-contained, so this can be called *anywhere*, either in individual views, or even your layout.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing LoginModel instance to the partial view

```
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <p> Welcome to my website</p>
}
else
{
    @await Html.PartialAsync("Account/Login", new LoginModel())
}
```

Comment: I have `@model IndexModel` and I need the index model so I am getting `One or more compilation references are missing. Ensure that your project is referencing 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' and the 'PreserveCompilationContext' property is not set to false.`

Comment: What if you pass null instead of an LoginModel() instance? - `@await Html.PartialAsync("Account/Login", null)`. I think you were getting the `InvalidOperationException' because the IndexModel is being passed into Login view where it expects LoginModel. And I didn't understand the second error you mentioned in the comment. Could  you please elaborate on when you are getting this?

Comment: When I used ` @await Html.PartialAsync("Account/Login", new LoginModel())` I got this `There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'signInManager' of 'LoginModel.LoginModel(SignInManager<ApplicationUser>, ILogger<LoginModel>)'` I tried nulll but it is saying `The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'CS.Pages.IndexModel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'CS.Pages.Account.LoginModel'.` I have added the login constructor to my question.

Comment: Passing null model after casting it to `LoginModel` should fix that issue. `@await Html.PartialAsync("Account/Login", (LoginModel)null)`. Another option is to keep it as a property of IndexModel and pass that which is mentioned in this link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/35927653/8879188