# Html.Action or Html.Partial not working with Attribute Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

i have a simple test controller defined as

```
[Route("~/testAction/testcontroller/{viewhash}")]
public ActionResult ATest(string viewHash)
        {
            var viewname = commonDataCollection.Instance.WidgetHashList[viewHash];
            return Content($"Success hash by view name is: {viewhash}","text/html");
        }
```

this works if i call this from browser http://localhost:49359/testAction/testcontroller/FuMmWA1217dgnaT

the below works if i use actual action/controller name instead of attribute route value but if i try to do the same with `Html Helper` with routing defined such as :

```
@Html.Action("testAction", new { viewhash = "FuMmWA1217dgnaT",area="",controller= "testcontroller" });
```

or

```
@Html.Partial("testAction", new { viewhash = "FuMmWA1217dgnaT",area="",controller= "testcontroller" });
```

or even when i am trying the render functions, i am getting following error:

> Execution of the child request failed. Please examine the
>   InnerException for more information. at
>   System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap[TResult](Func`1
>   func) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) at
>   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler,
>   TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage,
>   VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception
>   error, String queryStringOverride) at
>   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter
>   writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage) at
>   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter
>   writer, Boolean preserveForm) at
>   System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper.Execute(IHttpHandler handler,
>   TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.ActionHelper(HtmlHelper
>   htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName,
>   RouteValueDictionary routeValues, TextWriter textWriter) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(HtmlHelper
>   htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName,
>   RouteValueDictionary routeValues) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(HtmlHelper
>   htmlHelper, String actionName, Object routeValues) at
>   ASP._Page_Views_widgetrenders_contact_cshtml.Execute() in
>   D:\Projects\company
>   projects\CMSAlpha\CMSAlpha\Views\widgetrenders\contact.cshtml:line 20
>   The controller for path '/2/abc' was not found or does not implement
>   IController. System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The controller for
>   path '/2/abc' was not found or does not implement IController. at
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
>   requestContext, String controllerName) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass7.<BeginProcessRequest>b__6()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap[TResult](Func`1
>   func) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
>   requestContext, String controllerName) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__6()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap[TResult](Func`1
>   func)

Comment: Pretty sure that what you're trying to do can't be done. Html.Action expects the name of the action method in your controller. Not anything to do with routes.

Comment: @Tobias is there anyway to initiate this using route values, should i look for extension method approach... i must have this functionality to call right controller and get response.

Comment: @Tobias https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30382953/html-renderaction-with-route-name according to this i think its pretty much possible, not sure why mine is causing issues

Comment: What in that suggests that it's possible?

Comment: If you're going to hard code the route (which is what your doing if you use part of the route there) then there is no point in using `Html.Action` at all. Just hard code the whole URL. The whole point of using `Html.Action` is so that you can change the route in one place and not have to update it everywhere it is used.

Comment: @GabrielLuci got it, but my problem is i want to hide the controller method name and only expose the friendly route to whoever is writing the view, now i can grab the data using ajax... but we want to render it server side due to project flow requires as such, if an extension method can do this lookup i am all upto it

Comment: How can you hide the controller method name from someone who is writing code in the same project?

Comment: its an abstract system using different projects as plugins in IoC, so although the other users/developer can look through public methods using intellisense they dont know where to look for if we dont tell them

Comment: If they can use `Html.Action` then intellisense will help them find the name of the controller action.

Comment: Mate, you are trying to do the very opposite of what you should. Exactly as pointed by @GabrielLuci, you completely missed the reason why these helper exist. And the linked question works only because the method name is the same as word used in the route.

Comment: @AlKepp thanks for yours and Gabriel's comments, i think its not possible without hiding behind many methods so if i come up with something i will post solution here in future.